# ajax post to mvc receiving 302 (redirect) in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, http-status-code-302

I'm investigating a problem for around 2 weeks and I can't find a solution.

I have one ajax calling that is receiving redirect (302) just in production environment and just for this calling.

I've searched for all possibilities that I've found and until now I couldn't find why the redirect is happening.

I've checked authorization, version of the code, IIS configurations and so on, but nothing at all solved the problem.

The request as you can see bellow, is an upload of a simple .csv file. I have another similar request (actually it is identical) that is working fine both on homologation and production environment. Just this calling isn't working and only for the production environment.

Ajax post:

```js
function SubmitButtonOnclick() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById("selecionaEmail").files[0];
    formData.append("selecionaEmail", file);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ModalEmailsUpload", "Mail")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var count = 0;
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                count++;
            });

            if (count > 0) {
                $("#mensagem").css("color", "#3f8324");
                $("#mensagem").text("File uploaded. Choose one option:");
 
                if ($("#pfIncluir").is(":disabled")) {
                    $("#pfIncluir").removeAttr('disabled');
                }

                if ($("#pfExcluir").is(":disabled")) {
                    $("#pfExcluir").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("#mensagem").css("color", "#ff0000");
            $("#mensagem").text(error.responseText);
            $("#pfIncluir").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#pfExcluir").attr("disabled", true);

        }
    });
```

The action signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModalEmailsUpload()
    {
        //it's just returning a string as result of the validation
    }
```

Here the logs I took from browser:

Homologation:

```
POST /Mail/ModalEmailsUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: ***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: ***
Content-Length: 362
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------322973251128192
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=jo2j042lp2xsnzsjsslddmf0; .Login=07E0F5F86E9EF39DC84A926E79C414B2E5802286712F9FB439106E31200CF139CF78E0EA8B6A680DD3CE80DE388EBEAC8176392FFDCFCFEFDC905BBA4AA0D66671E5A980C5CABDF677B88FB1C37F13F458B92ED3F1906AFDB7616AA010C34B0559F426D8F6807E8548B5E9E95A4F1891F0B28DA9D2CF03FC3D850C3961AE1C03FDD3FE2ABCC3F3221D2E8D361C7D3C93783E5A68F3FE9B764A56FB9E0DF1A780; __RequestVerificationToken=GsjCurVxu6w5ZJWY6fn5bk-8QYwkOo-NU8kP_48_eVnSjNE_VgpS9QTKIz4rd4W43H5DM1zLD5Ei-Chmgua4G77ylNSX2yOdGHEwV6bZ_UA1
Connection: keep-alive
-----------------------------322973251128192
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selecionaEmail"; filename="_csv_virgula - parcial.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

CP,LOJA,EMAIL
10001,111,test1@teste.com.br
-----------------------------322973251128192--

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Production:

```
POST /Mail/ModalEmailsUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: ***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: ***
Content-Length: 358
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4390192952067
Cookie: .Login=40DDB91B4FCD780BD93E2B32BE6D603444BAA74AD3DE6440E55372C23B48A25BE74C15F91A3161800B5B049AB2E6045EB660E016D167CB1A3D7DE5F10C71ED83105365E42E99BDAEC620559C6FC5C36D0840C8B4ECA5DBE76ED20DF212AE5A4EC2D9B105F3FE5DEEDF3406D35A24FAD7FC6927236CC29DE55ACC3C55EBCD6DEFF6F5F597164DD3625105E9708C421B0240AF2CCC53BD9293E86276A151F6E432; ASP.NET_SessionId=y25h2jwy4pukqqo0nl0oz30n; __RequestVerificationToken=g1o3D2naXZUJS4dakmMdzn9T1OQ4lScnjrYdKOhM-s3H5ZhkSpq9JnOMv51N-GQJ-gn2yspgPSQC39H9OPVPcBXOCaHW0V2bVrj8UHUBZ9A1
Connection: keep-alive
-----------------------------4390192952067
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selecionaEmail"; filename="_csv_virgula - parcial.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

CP,LOJA,EMAIL
10001,111,test1@teste.com.br
-----------------------------4390192952067--

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /Erro?aspxerrorpath=/Mail/ModalEmailsUpload
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
----------------------------------------------------------

GET /Erro?aspxerrorpath=/Mail/ModalEmailsUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: ***
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: ***
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cookie: .Login=40DDB91B4FCD780BD93E2B32BE6D603444BAA74AD3DE6440E55372C23B48A25BE74C15F91A3161800B5B049AB2E6045EB660E016D167CB1A3D7DE5F10C71ED83105365E42E99BDAEC620559C6FC5C36D0840C8B4ECA5DBE76ED20DF212AE5A4EC2D9B105F3FE5DEEDF3406D35A24FAD7FC6927236CC29DE55ACC3C55EBCD6DEFF6F5F597164DD3625105E9708C421B0240AF2CCC53BD9293E86276A151F6E432; ASP.NET_SessionId=y25h2jwy4pukqqo0nl0oz30n; __RequestVerificationToken=g1o3D2naXZUJS4dakmMdzn9T1OQ4lScnjrYdKOhM-s3H5ZhkSpq9JnOMv51N-GQJ-gn2yspgPSQC39H9OPVPcBXOCaHW0V2bVrj8UHUBZ9A1
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Cookie entry in the two log files you will note that the production call does not have the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie that the Homologation call has.

This would indicate that the user is not logged in on the production server.

The redirect is to an error page because the original page generated an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. This indicates that something that is needed isn't available on the on the production server.

It isn't possible to identify what is causing 500 error without seeing the source for the ModalEmailsUpload that you om and knowing what the error message is.

Comment: Actually the request in production has the ASP.NET_SessionId, but it's after the cookie value. Do you know if the order of this tags could change the response? I didn't posted the code of the action because the request is being redirected before hit the controller.

Comment: The request is hitting the controller. The controller action is throwing an exception. This causes the redirect that you are seeing. The redirect is to `/Erro?aspxerrorpath=/Mail/ModalEmailsUpload`

Answer (score 0):

I have find problem of my system. So try it.

1. Check security of folder you upload, remember from document.
2. Right-click -> Properties -> Security (tab)
3. Choose account IIS using running
4. Check Permission and turn on full access (or something like write-read)
5. Done it

Hope you success.